# Values are repeating while joining multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to fetch data from multiple tables which contains various details of users from different tables.
Problem is that while joining it is showing repeated values

```
ID  NAME    DOB GENDER  CITY    RELATIONSHIP_STATUS ABOUT_ME    PROFILE_PIC_PATH    EMPLOYEER   JOB EMP_START   EMP_END EMP_VISIBILITY  SCHOOL  MAJOR   EDU_START   EDU_END EDU_VISIBILITY  IM_ON_SITE  IM_IM   IM_VISIBILITY   ADDRESS STATE   CONTRY  ZIP ADDRESS_VISIBILITY  ADDRESS_TYPE
1   ABC DEF August, 08 2011 00:00:00+0000   m   Durg    Single  hiii    /usr/img/p1.jpg google,google,google,google,google,google,google,google,google,google,google,google,yahoo,yahoo,yahoo,yahoo,yahoo,yahoo,yahoo,yahoo,yahoo,yahoo,yahoo,yahoo,facebook,facebook,facebook,facebook,facebook,facebook,facebook,facebook,facebook,facebook,facebook,facebook
```

Link of my online query is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5922/6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function you can just add `DISTINCT` to delete duplicates.

Like

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT column_name)
```

Comment: Is there any other way for doing the same

Comment: What's the problem with it?

Comment: No problem, I just want to know if there any other way to do this

Answer (score 0):

Use DISTINCT clause

```
group_concat(distinct emp.employeer ) as employeer,
```

Comment: @Venomis Just FYI, it's not best practice on stackoverflow to post the same answer twice.

Comment: i know but i've posted it 20 sec later u sr